# Perl Python interoperability

Tags: python, perl

Is there any way where I can make Perl and Python talk to each other?

I have tried [`Inline::Python`](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline::Python) and `__DATA__` but they call Python from Perl and I am looking something for calling Perl code from Python.

I have tried with [`PyPerl`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPerl)/`perlmodle` but that doesn't seem to be promising.

I would prefer some inbuilt method (like `__DATA__`) rather than using external modules.

Comment: What do you mean by `perlmodle`?

Comment: Why can't you use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and capture the output of the perl script?

Comment: Not enough info. What are you trying to do?